# SIPP: ERROR OPENING TERMINAL: CYGWIN

Tags: cygwin, sip

I have been trying to install sipp [on windows] to test a point-to-point SIP application that I am writing.   I installed sipp 3.2 as per instructions given [here](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html#Stable+release). I also installed cygwin. I am unable to run sipp even from from the same folder where I installed and it terminates with the cygwin error. Incidentally running just sipp provides the help documentation, but running any of the provided scenarios fails. Any thoughts?

```
Run sipp with embedded server (uas) scenario:
 ./sipp -sn uas
On the same host, run sipp with embedded client (uac) scenario
 ./sipp -sn uac 127.0.0.1


C:\Program Files\Sipp_3.2>sipp -sn uas
Error opening terminal: cygwin.

C:\Program Files\Sipp_3.2>sipp -sn uac
Error opening terminal: cygwin.
```

Comment: What's the error? I've run sipp on Windows in the past although I can't recall what hoops I had to jump through if any.

Comment: When running in the command prompt of the sipp install folder and when running inside cygwin the error is the same 'Error opening terminal: cygwin'

Comment: When I was installing sipp I gave up on the cygwin install and used the win32 setup exe from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sipp/files/sipp/3.2/.

Comment: 3.2 Windows recompiled setup, is the one I downloaded and installed, I didnt compile it in cygwin. I remember it being easier when I did this couple of years back, hence the question, if anything changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the resulting sipp executable from the Windows cmd shell, you have to set the  the
SIPPINSTDIR environment variable to the location of the executable. Without it, you'll get the "Error opening terminal: cygwin." error. For example, SET SIPPINSTDIR=c:\Users\me\Downloads\sipp.svn.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete (rename) cygwin1.dll provided with sipp.
Use cygwin1.dll provided with cygwin instead.
This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like SIPP doesn't know how to deal with a TERM of type cygwin. Try changing the TERM to something SIPP recognizes or try installing the `termcap` package from Utils (via Cygwin's Setup.exe).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with sipp version 3.2 for windows XP and windows 7. So i tried version 3.1 and it worked like a charm without cygwin.

You can set the environment system variable 'path' for sipp in MyComputer->Properties->Advanced Settings->Environment Varaibles.
Append the path below to the Environment Varaible "path"

;C:\Program Files\Sipp_3.1 ==> For Windows XP
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sipp_3.1 For Windows 7

Open the Window Shell and run the command 'sipp -sn uas'

Note: Install the wireshark latest version to get the winpcap library which i believe is required for sipp.